# what is the use of jQuery.parseXML()

Tags: jquery, xml

I was reading the document https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/. 
It says `Jquery.parseXML(string)` Parses a well formed XML string into an XML document.I am just confused what is difference between a well formed xml string and xml document and xml object , I  just can't understand what  `jQuery.parseXML()` really does, Can someone explain what this method really does with an example.

Comment: An XML document lets you use the DOM functions on it, while a string is just a string.

Comment: An XML document is an object structure. See [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: BTW, there's an example in the page you link to, which makes your question rather unclear.

Comment: Still unclear for me , we use`simplexml_load_string` in php to  converts xml string to xml object , what does that really mean , does it convert wellformed xml string to xml document, can someone explain in detail @DenysSéguret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is just textual information. You could open in Notepad, display it in your console, send it in an email, etc. It doesn't carry any intrinsic meaning or function.

An XML document is an object which is constructed *from* a string. It gives you functions just like working with the DOM. You can search for nodes, add nodes, remove nodes, etc.

**TL;DR** A string is just text, an XML document is an object.

Comment: does it mean xml document is xml object, then does `simplexml_load_string` converts xml string to xml document(xml object)

Comment: @beginner Essentially, yes. They wouldn't use `simplexml_load_string` since it's a PHP function but it has the same result.

Comment: just to be sure , u mean `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [to] => Tove [from] => Jani [heading] => Reminder [body] => Don't forget me this weekend! )`Is an xml document(object) for some xml string  `<?php
$note=<<<XML
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
XML;`

Comment: @beginner You got it!

Comment: Thanks man . I thought it converted to object using `$xml = $( xmlDoc )` And xml document is different thing , In my question's link an example given can u tell why they use `$xml = $( xmlDoc )`  if it already converted into  object

Answer (score 1):

A "well formed XML string" is a string of valid XML code (e.g. it contains a doctype like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>).
A "XML document" is not just text but an already parsed object.

The jQuery page for parseXML() has an example:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/